# Binding a socket to specific network

Tags: c++, udp

My computer is connected to multiple networks, say `Network A` and `Network B`.
I want to receive UDP broadcast packets from Network B only.

Currently, I am opening an UDP Socket and binding it to INADDR_ANY.

```
sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address.sin_port = htons( (unsigned short) 11000 );

if ( bind( handle, (const sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(sockaddr_in) ) < 0 )
{
       //Operation Failed!
       return false;
}
```

How to make sure that I will be receiving messages from Network B only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The broadcast address is going to end with all-1 bits, so assuming "hoNetAddr" is a host-ordered address:

```
uint32_t hoBcastAddr = (hoNetAddr & hoNetMask) | (~hoNetMask);
// e.g. 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 =>
//      (C0A80000 & FFFFFF00) | (/*inverted netmask*/ 000000FF)
// broadcast is: C0A800FF
address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(hoBcastAddr);
```

(assuming IPv4)

Comment: Isn't `(~0 & ~hoNetMask)` equivalent to `(~hoNetMask)`?